# Show ProgressBar after the RecyclerView list

Tags: android, list, listview, android-recyclerview, progress-bar

i want to show ProgressBar after the end of RecyclerView's list.. currently when i scroll down ProgressBar show on the last item and when new posts fetched the last item disappeared..
searched on google but couldn't find answer, i am new as developer, please help

[image]

this is my xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">




    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        tools:ignore="NotSibling" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

progress bar:

```
 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) && dy > 0)
            { //check for scroll down
                visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                    if (!loading){
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        loading = true;
                        yourURL = baseURL + baseModel + "&page=" + pageNo++;
                        getRetrofit();

                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a progress bar in recycleView you have to use pagination3.
In paginations3 they have provided how to show progress bar if network is slow and if a network is not there then it will show a Retry Button so I am suggesting you to read an article on Pagination3 it will solve you all problem.